# double summation binomial coefficient

Tags: analysis, summation, binomial-coefficients, absolute-convergence

I have the following sum to evaluate: $ \sum_\limits{l,k=0}^{\infty} \binom{l}{k}  (-1)^kr^{k-2l} $ .

I feel like I first have to establish absolute convergence for a certain range of values of $|r|$ but I'm not sure how to do that.

Next I think I can then use a double summation  like so: 
$ \sum_\limits{l=0}^{\infty}\sum_\limits{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{l}{k}  (-1)^kr^{k-2l} = \sum_\limits{l=0}^{\infty}\sum_\limits{k=0}^{l} \binom{l}{k}    (-1)^kr^{k-2l} $ but I'm not sure how to evaluate the sum from that point on.

Comment: You should recognise $r^{-2l}\sum_{k = 0}^l \binom{l}{k}(-1)^kr^k$ if you look at it for a bit.

Comment: yes your're right thanks. it's $r^{-2l} (1-r)^l $, right?

Comment: Right. And we're left with a geometric series. And the task to find out when the manipulations are justified. To find the range of $\lvert r\rvert$ where we have absolute convergence is rather easy. If you need to check whether everything is legitimate for some values outside that range, that can get fussy.

Comment: But don't I have to establish a range of $|r|$ for absolute convergence in the original expression? In order to even write down a double summation "by row"? And the binomial coefficient $\binom{l}{k}$ can get very big no?

Comment: In general, absolute convergence is a sufficient, but not a necessary condition to justify a particular rearrangement. Now here we have $\sum_{l,k = 0}^\infty$, and unless there are special conventions in place for a double-indexed sum, indeed absolute convergence is necessary for the sum to be well-defined [actually, the special form of the terms ensures that all terms are positive when $r < 0$, so in that case the sum is well-defined even if it diverges to $+\infty$. Meh.]. That last remark however points to how to prove things. If all terms are nonnegative, you can rearrange as you please.

Comment: The value of the sum, whether finite or $+\infty$ doesn't change under arbitrary rearrangements. So just drop the $(-1)^k$, put absolute value bars around $r$, and rearrange until you get a geometric series, then you have the condition that its ratio must be smaller than $1$ for convergence.

Comment: nice stuff, thanks. I get, as a condition for absolute convergence: $ |\frac{1+r}{r^2}| < 1$

Comment: That should be $\dfrac{1 + \lvert r\rvert}{\lvert r\rvert^2} < 1$.

Comment: true. I forgot to say I was just doing the case for r>0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering $$S=\sum_{l=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{l}{k}  (-1)^kr^{k-2l} =\sum_{l=0}^{\infty}r^{-2l}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{l}{k}  (-r)^k \right)=\sum_{l=0}^{\infty}{r^{-2l}}{(1-r)^l}$$ $$S=\sum_{l=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1-r}{r^2}\right)^l=\frac{r^2}{r^2+r-1}$$